# convert one xml to another xml with xslt using javascript

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

is there any Javascript library or function which take xml file and xsl file and generate output xml file using xslt. ?

Please give some suggestion.
Thanks.

Comment: On which platform, in which environment do you use Javascript?

Comment: i am using it on local server. windows 7 + firefox.

Comment: If you want to use XSLT on Windows then you can use Javascript in Windows Script Host and automate MSXML, Microsoft's COM based XSLT 1.0 processor. Firefox is of course something completely different, if you run Javascript inside of a Mozilla browser then see https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Using_the_Mozilla_JavaScript_interface_to_XSL_Transformations.